# Regex split and merge into single record

Tags: c#, regex, arraylist, split

> In my C# application I'm using the below Regex to split the string ([A-Z0-9]{20}\d{0}). But it is splitting the ErrorCode and ErrorMsg as two different records but I need ErrorCode and ErrorMgs in the Single Array record.
> For Example:
> Current Logic:

> [0] 05300030000GN0030018

> [1 Field is required.
>
> But I need like below one
> [0] 05300030000GN0030018Field is required.
>
> Current Implementation:

[image: My Regex logic is returning like this]

> Expected output

[image: But I need this format by using Regex]

Comment: Why not `input.Split('.')`? Or, `Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=\.)")` if the `.` must still be there?

Comment: We shouldn’t split by (.) because sometimes the error message will come by multiple dots

Comment: Ok, I understand `\d{0}` was used in hope to fail the match if the next char after `[A-Z0-9]{20}` is a digit, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `msg` is never empty and `\d{0}` was used to fail any match if the next char after `[A-Z0-9]{20}` is a digit, you can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[A-Z0-9]{20}\D.*?(?=\b[A-Z0-9]{20}\D|\z)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a24huf/1). Note that in case `msg` can be empty you need to use a `(?!\d)` lookahead instead of `\D`, `@"\b[A-Z0-9]{20}(?!\d).*?(?=\b[A-Z0-9]{20}(?!\d)|\z)"`.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary (need to make sure the char limit is fine)
- `[A-Z0-9]{20}` - twenty uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `\D` - a non-digit char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\b[A-Z0-9]{20}\D|\z)` - a positive lookahead that requires a word boundary, twenty uppercase ASCII letters or digits and a non-digit or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.